# All query highlight in apache solr

Tags: solr, highlight

As I am trying to do highlighting in apache solar. I see it highlights even single words in lines. I want to highlight if all query matches. how can i set parameters for that?

I do not want to highlight single words in a query. Highlight only if all query matches in a line.

query - What is synchronization and why is it important

result 
1) `What is <em>synchronization</em> and why is it <em>important</em>?`
2) `What is typically the MOST <em>important</em> reason to use risk to drive testing efforts?`

iIdon't want to highlight queries with single word match i want to highlight only those with exact match. so how can I configure highlight in solar.

and is there another way i can get field name for matched text.

Comment: Could you please provide us with your Solr configuration and an example query with result?

Comment: query - Describe synchronization in respect to multithreading. and responce i get is - 1)  "Question":["<em>Describe</em> <em>synchronization</em> in <em>respect</em> to <em>multithreading</em>."]}, 2)  "Question":["What is <em>synchronization</em> and why is it important?"]}, i dont want to highlight second word match responce how can i configure it.

Comment: @user6414153 Better if you update your question instead of adding comments with relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: All you need to know about configuring the Solr highlighter are in the [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting).

Long answer: You should configure the `hl.usePhraseHighlighter` Parameter to `true`. Solr will highlight phrase queries accurately as phrases. Normally, the parts of the phrase will be highlighted everywhere instead of only when it forms the given phrase.

Comment: yes i set it as true still it highlights different words. i pass query as java classes it highlight java and classes in different tags. i want to tag a query together how can i do that

Comment: If you want the complete phrase `java classes` to match, you should put them in quotes like `"java classes"`.

Comment: "java classes" this is my query.. and i got highlighted result "<span>java</span> <span>classes</span>" like this but i want highlighted result like "<span>java classes</span>".. How can i get this kind of highlighting